# How does one add a reference to a multi-value ReferenceField using code?

Tags: plone, archetypes

Let's day I've got an Archtypes based object with a multi-valued reference field ReferenceField as per the following:

```
schema = BaseSchema.copy() + Schema((
    ReferenceField(
        'SomeObjects',
        multiValued=1,
        allowed_types=('SomeObjects',),
        relationship = 'ThisObjectSomeObject',
    )
))

class ThisObject(BaseContent):
    schema = schema
```

How would I go about adding a reference to the `SomeObjects` field using code?

Comment: What do you mean with "how"? Plone -> Add menu -> your content -> Choose reference? Or in a test? or debug console? Does your at content works properly?

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect the fact that I wanted to know how to do it with code.

Comment: Ok, so then you have already two answers. I'll add a third one :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grab the field's value, modify it, and set the field.  You can add an instance directly, or use the UID string.

Something like this:

```
val = instance.getSomeObjects()
val = val if val else []
val.append(uid)
instance.setSomeObjects(val)
```

Comment: Setting a multiValued reference field with a single value instead of a list is supported.

Answer (score 1):

This example uses the `File` content type and the `relatedItems` field of plone, to show you how the ReferenceField works

Assume that `plone`is your Plone Site.

```python
# Create two files
>>> plone.invokeFactory('File', 'file1')
file1
>>> plone.invokeFactory('File', 'file2')
file2

# Set reference from file1 to file2
# Since relatedItems is also multi valued like your field you have to pass a list of objects.
>>> plone.file1.setRelatedItems([file2])

# With the `regular` getter you got the objects
>>> plone.file1.getRelatedItems()
[<ATFile at /Plone/file2>]

# With the special raw getter you got the UID of the objects
>>> plone.file1.getRawRelatedItems()
['e1486e46376545db92f911c48dae5c69']

# You can also pass the UID of the object to the setter
plone.fil1.setRelatedItems([file2.UID()])

>>> plone.file1.getRelatedItems()
[<ATFile at /Plone/file2>]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming here that you're asking how do you programmatically save a reference to another object from an instance of ThisObject?

If so you just need to pass in the UID of the object you wish to reference:

```
object.setSomeObjects(otherObject.UID())
```

Comment: Don't remember it this works either, but probably you must pass a sequence of uids

Comment: ... I mean: because it's multi valued